# Is it a requirement to specify module dependencies in both module-info.java and build.gradle.kts

Tags: java, gradle, java-module

This is my multi-project Gradle setup:

```
.
└── gradle-module-project
    ├── application
    ├── build.gradle.kts
    ├── gradlew
    ├── list
    ├── settings.gradle.kts
    └── utilities
```

`application`, `utilties` and `list` are projects, and inside each one there is a Java Module.

That is, each project has its own `src/main/java/module-info.java` file and `build.gradle.kts` file.

`application` module depends on `utilities` module, and `utilities` module depends on `list` module.

`build.gradle.kts` at the root contains the following:

```
subprojects {
    ..

    plugins.withType<JavaPlugin>().configureEach {
        configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
            modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
        }
    }
    
    ..
}
```

What I find strange is that inside each sub-project, the `build.gradle.kts` is required to list the dependencies.

For example, `application` -> `build.gradle.kts` contains:

```
plugins {
    application
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":utilities"))
}

..
```

Why does `build.gradle.kts` for `application` have to include `implementation(project(":utilities"))`?

When the `module-info.java` inside `application` already specifies what that module depends on.

Doesn't this seem like duplication?

Is it intended that the dependency must be specified in both `module-info.java` and `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: Not dealing much in Gradle, but looks similar to specifying an artifact dependency before actually using one of its classes within the project class. If you compile or run the project with just the java command-line tools, you just need to make sure the dependencies are part of the modulepath or classpath. I believe that's what Gradle's property might be facilitating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Java Modules with Gradle, dependencies have to be specified twice: once for the benefit of the module system and again for the benefit of the build tool.

I've been following along with the Easy Text demo application in [Java 9 Modularity](https://javamodularity.com/) by Sandor Mak and Paul Bakker, which is a multi-module project. The `module-info.java` for one module is:

```java
module easytext.cli {
   requires easytext.analysis;
}
```

When I wrap it in Gradle, in my `build.gradle` file I also need:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation project(':easytext.analysis')
}
```

Perhaps it's just a matter of time before the tooling catches up and we won't have to do both.

Also check out Paul Bakker's JavaOne presentation [Building JPMS Modules with Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haOaA4MYUGA) in which he goes through the fine-detail of building multiple-module Java/Groovy/Kotlin projects with Gradle.